# Conditionally enable a sub-type (similar to enable_if to enable functions)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

I have a traits class which defines types for "ranges" (or containers, sequences) by deducing the type of member functions, like this:

```
template<class R>
struct range_type_traits
{
    // "iterator": The type of the iterators of a range
    using iterator = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<R>()));

    // "value_type": The (non-reference) type of the values of a range
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*(std::declval<iterator>()))>::type;
};
```

The reason I do this (and not using the subtypes of `R` directly or `std::iterator_traits`) is to support any type of container in some templated library that has a `begin()` member and doesn't require the container to have some `value_type` / `iterator` types defined. As far as I know, `std::iterator_traits` can't handle some kind of "key type" for containers which don't expose their iterator interface to STL using pairs, like `std::map` does (example: `QMap<K,T>` has `value_type = T`. You can access the key via [`iterator::key()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap-iterator.html).).

Now I want to conditionally define a type `key_type` iif the `iterator` has a function `::key() const` and take its return type, similar to what I do with the `value_type`. If I just put the definition in the existing traits class, compilation fails for containers not supporting this.

SFINAE with `std::enable_if` can conditionally enable template functions. How to conditionally extend an existing class / conditionally define a sub-type?

Something like this sketch:

```
template<class R>
struct range_type_traits
{
    // "iterator": The type of the iterators of a range
    using iterator = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<R>()));

    // "value_type": The (non-reference) type of the values of a range
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*(std::declval<iterator>()))>::type;

    ENABLE_IF_COMPILATION_DOES_NOT_FAIL {
        // "key_type": The (non-reference) type of the keys of an associative range not using pairs in its STL-interface
        using key_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<iterator>().key())>::type;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use SFINAE on class templates to create a base class template that defines `key_type` if and only if the condition you require is satisfied:

```
namespace detail
{

    // Primary template (does not define key_type)
    template<typename R, typename = void>
    struct key_type_definer { };

    // Specialization using SFINAE to check for the existence of key() const
    // (does define key_type)
    template<typename R>
    struct key_type_definer<
        R,
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<
                decltype(std::declval<R const>().key()),
                decltype(std::declval<R const>().key())
                >::value
            >::type
        >
    {
        // Type alias definition
        using key_type = typename std::remove_reference<
            decltype(std::declval<R const>().key())
            >::type;
    };

} // end namespace detail
```

Then, you could derive your `range_traits` class template from the `key_type_definer` class template, this way:

```
template<class R>
struct range_type_traits : detail::key_type_definer<R>
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
};
```

`range_type_traits` will now define a type alias called `key_type` if and only if `R` has a member function `R key() const`, where `R` will be the type aliased by `key_type`.

Comment: Give me a second to try this out. Might take a while, I'm just learning type traits, SFINAE, enable_if, etc. Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: It seems to work (after changing R in the inheritance to the iterator type of R, since key() is defined on the iterator, not on R itself). But I don't understand why my solution fails. Let me show you my approach, maybe you can tell my what's wrong: http://ideone.com/LJnRQ3 -- Any tips on how to "debug" such stuff? It really sucks to guess things until it works, if you know what I mean...

Comment: Nice answer, as usual. I just want to mention a simplification. Define the primary template by `template<typename R, typename = int>
struct key_type_definer { };` and the specialization by `template<typename R> struct key_type_definer<R, decltype(std::declval<R const>().key(), 0)> { /* same as before */ }`. Sorry for putting "lots" of code in a comment but I don't think this is worth an answer on its own.

Comment: Also, I don't get why my sub-types defined in the super class `range_basic_type_traits` aren't availabe. I remember I have to prepend typename if I access sub-types, but not that I have to prepend the super class name.

Comment: In my approach (see my comment), the remove_reference doesn't seem to be evaluated. When trying to assign an instance of `K = ...::key_type` to the *real* key type I used in a test range type, it says: `conversion from 'K {aka std::remove_reference<const [REAL_KEY_TYPE]&>}' to non-scalar type '[REAL_KEY_TYPE]' requested`. I don't want to stick to my approach, but I want to *understand* what's going on here...

Comment: @leemes: It seems you forgot the `::type` after your `std::remove_reference<>` template: it should be `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<typename range_basic_type_traits<R>::iterator>().key())>::type`

Comment: @leemes: With that correction, your example [compiles here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t$341)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Hard to see such details... ;) Thank you both for your solutions!

Comment: My final solution: http://ideone.com/DyoebO -- Thank you both, also @CassioNeri for the cleaner syntax without enable_if thanks to the new decltype. Very nice. ;)